# How to create a letter spacing attribute with pycairo?

Tags: python, pygobject, pango

I'm using Pango + Cairo (through GObject) to render text with python3.7, and would like to set the *letter spacing* by creating an attribute and attaching that attribute to my pango layout.

In the gnome documentation for pango, I can see that there should be a function called [`pango_attr_letter_spacing_new`](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/func.attr_letter_spacing_new.html) (since v1.6). However, if I run `Pango.attr_letter_spacing_new`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Pango' object has no attribute 'attr_letter_spacing_new'
```

This feels a bit strange, since I can use the [`pango_attr_type_get_name`](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/type_func.AttrType.get_name.html) which should only have been available since v1.22.

I have a work-around by using [markup](https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/pango/PangoMarkupFormat.html) with `<span letter_spacing="1234">` but I would rather not go down this route.

### Minimal "Working" Example

```py
# pip install pycairo==1.18.0 pygobject==3.32.0

import cairo
import gi
gi.require_version('Pango', '1.0')
gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Pango, PangoCairo

width, height = 328, 48

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
layout = PangoCairo.create_layout(context)

font_desc = Pango.font_description_from_string('Sans, 40px')
layout.set_font_description(font_desc)

# What I can do
layout.set_markup(f'<span letter_spacing="{1024 * 10}">Hello World</span>')

# What I would like to do
if False:
    letter_spacing_attr = Pango.attr_letter_spacing_new(1024 * 10)

    attr_list = Pango.AttrList()
    attr_list.insert(letter_spacing_attr)
    layout.set_attributes(attr_list)

    layout.set_text('Hello World')

PangoCairo.show_layout(context, layout)

with open('help-me.png', 'wb') as image_file:
    surface.write_to_png(image_file)
```

#### Manually creating a LetterSpacing attribute

I have been able to find the enum value `Pango.AttrType.LETTER_SPACING`, which allows me to do something like this:

```
c = Pango.AttrClass()
c.type = Pango.AttrType.LETTER_SPACING
a = Pango.Attribute()
a.init(c)
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to set the value of it, and it makes me think it is the wrong way to approach things :|

Insert this into an `Pango.AttrList`, gave an error (not surprisingly) and made the python process segfault next time I did something with Pango:

```
** (process:17183): WARNING **: 12:00:56.985: (gi/pygi-struct-marshal.c:287):pygi_arg_struct_from_py_marshal: runtime check failed: (g_type_is_a (g_type, G_TYPE_VARIANT) || !is_pointer || transfer == GI_TRANSFER_NOTHING)
```

#### Other leads

.. that sadly have lead nowhere :(

- [pygtk listing a function `pango.AttrLetterSpacing`](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-pangoattribute.html)

  - `Pango.AttrLetterSpacing` => `'gi.repository.Pango' object has no attribute 'AttrLetterSpacing'`
  - `Pango.Attrbute.LetterSpacing` => `type object 'Attribute' has no attribute 'LetterSpacing'`
- the documentation for the pango packge for Vala (which seems to use GObject as well), also shows the [`attr_letter_spacing_new` function](https://valadoc.org/pango/Pango.attr_letter_spacing_new.html) -- this doesn't really help that much, but suggests that the function should be available through GObject, although I haven't tried.

Comment: Looking at the pygobject documentation from [this page](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Pango-1.0/mapping.html) it appears that the attr_letter_spacing_new function is unavailable without a python equivalent. This matches what was said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783670/pango-attributes-with-pygobject) as something lost in the pygtk -> pygobject transition.

Comment: Some further research that might possibly lead to a solution. The pitivi video editor project uses PyGObject. They apparently work around the defective `Pango.AttrList` class as shown [here](https://github.com/scorsin/pitivi/blob/327a6daf68b998210432e415ad30618ace4e18f6/pitivi/titleeditor.py).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon That's interesting, though they are pretty much reimplement it completely ("FIXME Fix Pango so we do NOT need that dirty reimplementation Pango.AttrList"). The `<span>` workaround suggested in the original question looks way cleaner (especially for the case when you need just this attribute and not all of them).

Comment: @MichalČihař Absolutely, just wanted to present what was out there. It probably would be best to use the "span" workaround. .format() syntax could always be used if you want to make a function where those numbers are passed into the span.

Comment: There is a significant problem with using markup, which is that you need to ensure the input is escaped. In our case, the input comes directly from the user, so that's why I wanted an other method :)

Comment: @RasmusWL is this still an issue? I have a similar problem and are tentatively going down the markup route. This seems to work well (assuming data is escaped correctly). My current problem is that the Pango bindings leaks refcounts.

Comment: @RasmusWL, can you tell which version of Pango you have installed?  I just tried  your example (setting the `if` marked with *What I would like to do* to `True`), and it worked fine.  I'm using 1.44.5.  I've been reading about how GObject Introspection works, and I'm very curious about the problem you faced.

Comment: @RasmusWL, I'd appreciate if you could run this, too: `strings /usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Pango-1.0.typelib | grep -i attr_letter_spacing_new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this issue was already solved, using pycairo 1.20.0 and PyGObject                3.40.1:

```py
import cairo
import gi
gi.require_version('Pango', '1.0')
gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Pango, PangoCairo

width, height = 328, 48

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
layout = PangoCairo.create_layout(context)

font_desc = Pango.font_description_from_string('Sans, 40px')
layout.set_font_description(font_desc)

letter_spacing_attr = Pango.attr_letter_spacing_new(1024 * 10)

attr_list = Pango.AttrList()
attr_list.insert(letter_spacing_attr)
layout.set_attributes(attr_list)

layout.set_text('Hello World')

PangoCairo.show_layout(context, layout)

with open('help-me.png', 'wb') as image_file:
    surface.write_to_png(image_file)
```

Comment: Confirmed to be working (pycairo 1.20.1, PyGObject 3.42.0)